# Nginx configuration mix

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to mix some configuration settings in Nginx? For example there is the auth_basic, which should work everywhere. And there is some other configuration spefic for one directory. Or there is the PHP interpreter...

```
# conf A
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    auth_basic $auth;
    auth_basic_user_file /var/www/admin/.htpasswd;
}

# conf B
location /awstats/classes/ {
    alias /usr/local/awstats/wwwroot/classes/;
}

# conf C
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

So what happens here: If the request ends with .php, the auth_basic doesn't work. On any request to /awstats/classes/ the auth_basic doesn't work.

Is there a way to cascade or mix different configurations? So Nginx uses conf A AND B for example?

Comment: Try to put the `auth_basic*` directives not inside a `location`, but instead into the `server` block.

Comment: My question is more general. I want to mix different configurations. To make some settings "global" is not what I want. It's more like templates. I'm searching a way to do something like "if location a or b do this ...". I thought there should be some configuration thing like procmail does. Procmail supports multiple recipes in chain (or not).

Comment: Maybe [this](http://rosslawley.co.uk/archive/old/2010/01/04/nginx-how-to-multiple-if-statements/) and [that](https://gist.github.com/Coopeh/4637216) helps.

Comment: By the way: If you want to deal with locations, maybe just using a pipe delimited location directive would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For this to work, you should read the documentation about `location` *matching*.

Comment: I already did this and it doesn't answer my question

Comment: It is. Keep rereading it in cycles until you will actually understand it.